# iOS: Check values? NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, didselectrowatindexpath

---

**Skip the following**

These values are the first three lines of a TVC didSelectRowAtIndexPath method which is giving me all kinds of exceptions when I select an item in a row.

How do I:

a. Check that the below dictionary, array and selectedCategory have values.

b. Ensure that they do if they turn out not to?

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"News"];
NSString *selectedCategory = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

---

**To here :**

Exception from UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7193a60

Comment: I think problem hides in first three lines. Check that dictionary, array and selectedCategory have values.

Comment: Thank you Madman, I've focused the scope of the question.

Comment: If the app is crashing then add an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator. This will stop the app before it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple adjustment. There are normally better ways to store data than nesting all these data collections, but this is a simple drop in replacement for what you have already that should stop the crashes.

```
// First check your listOfItems
NSDictionary *dictionary = NULL;
if (listOfItems.count > indexPath.section) {
    dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}

// Next check your dictionary isn't null.
NSArray *array = NULL;
if (dictionary) {
    array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"News"];
}

// Next check your array and make sure your array has values.
NSString *selectedCategory = NULL;
if (array.count > indexPath.row) {
   selectedCategory = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

// Finally do your stuff
if (selectedCategory) {
    // Do your stuff
} else {
    // Something went wrong along the way and you don't have a selectedCategory string.
}
```

Comment: I am doing something else wrong because I have the same issue after implementing your solution.

Comment: Update your question with the actual errors you're getting and we can work through them one by one :)

Comment: Exception from UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7193a60

Comment: Alright this exception has nothing to do with the parts of your question or my answer. You're setting your tableView.datasource to a uiview instead of your UIViewController instance. find that line and change it to self.

Comment: Glad I could :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that initWithString method of NSPlaceholderString got a nil as an argument.
So , to figure when this exactly happens, it would be good to add an exception breakpoint. Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)

Comment: I have done this, but it points me to the same spot in main.m as before.

Answer (score 0):

To check that they have values you can check...

```
[dictionary count];

[array count];

[selectedCategory length];
```

or you can check things like...

```
dictionary == nil;

array == nil;

[selectedCategory isEqualToString:@""];

selectedCategory == nil;
```

There are lots of ways. Not exactly sure what you are asking but you can check these.